# Can a sequence of $c_0$ be also a sequence of $l_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Provided that the norm of the space $c_0$ is $$||x||_\infty=\underset{1\le j\le\infty}{max}|x_j|$$, can one of its sequences, such as

$$x_1=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

be also member of its dual space $l_1$?

$l_1$ has a different norm,  $∥(a_i)∥_1=\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|$, while its dual space, $c_0$ has the norm  $||x||_\infty=\underset{1\le j\le\infty}{max}|x_j|$. Does this prohibit $x_1$ in being member of both spaces?

Comment: $l_1\subset c_0.$ (However, beware that $l_1$ is not *equal* to $(c_0)'$ but only (canonically) *isomorphic* to it.)

Comment: GOOD TO KNOW. THANKS ANN

Comment: Allways welcome. Beware also that the dual space of $l_1$ is not $c_0$ as you wrote, but $l_\infty.$

Comment: I see, so dual space is not a two-way relation!

Comment: You mean "$E\mapsto E'$ is not an involution" (with the same abuse of language, i.e. in fact the dual space of $l_1$ is even not $l_\infty$ but *isomorphic* to it). Banach spaces $E$ for which the canonical embedding of $E$ into $(E')'$ is onto are called [relexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Reflexive_Banach_spaces).

Comment: "abuse of language"! :) Thanks Anne!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of $l_1$ is an element of $c_0$, independently of the norms, but just because of the definition of these spaces (as vector spaces). In addition, you have a continuous inclusion of normed spaces $l_1\hookrightarrow c_0$.

Comment: SPECTACULAR, THANKS